# Getting OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded with Tomcat server in Linux machine

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory

I am getting "OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" with my Tomcat server in Linux Machine. Please let me know if there are any tools that helps me to analyze which program in my Java application is consuming lot of memory. Do we have any debugging tools that gives some information to know where tomcat sever failed with this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JDK comes with such a tool out of the box: `jvisualvm`.

Comment: Please check if it is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler

Comment: I am getting cmmand not found error when I run the command in Linux:`-bash-3.2$ jvisualvm
-bash: jvisualvm: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you set command line paramter: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to make heapdump on OOM. Also can be usefull: -XX:HeapDumpPath=<*folder for heap dump*>.

When OOM occurred you can analyze heap dump with [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). It is very useful tool to analyze heapdumps.

Also you can use [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) to make heap dumps manually. Example: `jmap -dump:file=<output-filename> <java process id>`

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I ran the jmap command by passing processid as input, I am getting error. Please help how to solve this issue: `-bash-3.2$ jmap 10865
Attaching to process ID 10865, please wait...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException                    Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VMVersionMismatchException: Supported versions are 20.0-b11. Target VM is 14.3-b01
`

Comment: @user2065083 here http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=974 several recipes how to solve your problem. Be sure you are run jmap same your Java version, which you take heapdump.